# How to know su password

Tags: security, root

You already know my question.

I don't have su authority.

So I want to know su password.

I really(x100) don't know how to find it.

I tried change direction(/etc/pam.d/su) and tried to delete `auth  sufficient pam_wheel.so trust`.

But I could not do it,Because I don't have su authority.

:-(

so...Could you do me a favor?

Comment: su password is usually root password. either the one you gave when you did install your system, or the one your sysadmin will gave you,  if you ask.

Comment: Which linux is this?

Answer (score 2):

I guess we are talking about YOUR system here.

Since you own the system the fastest way would be to change it.

If you are in the sudoers, you can `sudo bash` and then `passwd` to change root password.

If you're not, start your system with any live CD you have around, mount the drive where your system is in /mnt for instance, `chroot` to /mnt or where you mounted it and finally `passwd` to change the password.

After that, boot your system normally and you will be able to `su` or log in as root with the new password.